# Example of nonabelian group with all proper subgroups normal

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do we find an example of nonabelian group for which all proper subgroups are normal?? It's one of the questions on my study-guide sheet.  Thank you

Comment: @KReiser You are correct. I was thinking "non-cyclic" vs. "non-abelian". Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Do you know what the quaternion group is?

Comment: http://planetmath.org/HamiltonianGroup.html

Comment: Can we give an example other than the quaternions?

Answer (score 13):

Let $Q = \{1, -1, i, -i, j, -j, k, -k\}$ be the [quaternion group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group).
Let $Z$ be a subgroup of order $2$.
Since $-1$ is the only element of order $2$, $Z = \{1, -1\}$.
Since it is the only subgroup of order $2$, it is normal.
Let $H$ be a subgroup of order $4$.
Since $(Q : H) = 2, Q = H \cup aH = H \cup Ha$ for every $a \in Q - H$.
Hence $aH = Ha$.
Hence $H$ is normal.

Comment: Why the fact that $Z$ is the only subgroup of order $2$ implies it's normal?

Comment: @user42912 Because $aZa^{-1}$ is a subgroup of order $2$ for every $a \in Q$.